# ¿Cómo accedo al objeto distance de google-maps-api-3?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, api

Requiero extraer el valor de la distancia de una ruta que muestro utilizando la **API de Google Maps V3**. En la documentación veo que el **DirectionsResult** contiene los objetos *routes[]*, que a su vez contiene *legs[]*, y es ahí donde se ubican los objetos **duration** y **distance**; cada uno con sus correspondientes *value* y *text*.
Ahora, el código que he utilizado es:
`var elTiempo = directionsResult.routes[0].legs.duration.value;
        var laDistancia = directionsResult.routes[0].legs.distance.value;
        alert (elTiempo + laDistancia);`

Lo que intento es poder mostrar por separado en un div de mi página la información sobre distancia y tiempo, con mis propios estilos. Algo similar ocurre en esta guía de Google, en la que muestra la distancia total de la ruta por separado: *https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable?hl=es*

Este es mi primer proyecto con javascript y una API. Agradeceré enormemente cualquier ayuda y más el esfuerzo por explicar paso a paso. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la respuesta de `directionsService.route()` lo puedes hacer de esta manera, sumando las distancias de los "legs":

```
var route = response.routes[0];
var distance = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
  distance = distance + route.legs[i].distance.value;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shaz, tu respuesta me resultó muy útil con la distancia, pero ¿y el tiempo? Noté que en el **for** utilizas  _.lenght_ en lugar de _distance_

Comment: Si te das cuenta y haces un dump del objeto, la estructura es similar, por ende deberías poder hacer algo muy parecido para el tiempo.